# Commercial 'Help' creation tools available for .NET applications?

Tags: c#, .net, chm

I'm looking for some tool that can be used to create .chm (or something else that works with .NET) help files for my .NET application.  I realize that Microsoft offers a free product that works perfectly fine, but here is the caveat:  I work for a contractor that gets it's money from the gov't.  As you can imagine, we have certain processes in place that are simply there to waste time and money.  One of these is our process for approving "Free and/or Open Source Software."  Given that this microsoft tool is free, program management wants nothing to do with it..they'd much rather find one that they can buy and get a license for to remove any ambiguity about our legal rights to use it.  So yes, even though there is a perfectly good, free tool available, to satisfy management who doesn't want to deal with stupid, expensive, time consuming processes, I'm looking for something (that is probably less capable) that costs us money and will accomplish the same/similar thing.

Comment: "to remove any ambiguity about our legal rights to use it" reading license removes it faster and cheaper

Comment: that is what is called "efficient budget management"

Comment: How does paying some money magically make all legal problems go away? If you review licenses for free software, surely you also review the ones for commercial software...?

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen it is true that free licenses are tricky, GPL for example. There are much more caveats then in typical commercial one.

Comment: Does this policy apply to FOSS software or to any software that does not cost money?  In other words, which version of "Free" does this apply to?

Comment: @Andrey: But surely an organization like this would not rely on the license being "typical".

Comment: I will sell you a license for the MS tool.

Comment: I wish I had the answer...I may even be wrong about the reason for it being so difficult to get FOSS approval, but one of the process guys mentioned legal issues.  I just know that the process is extremely tedious and manages to waste more money than buying a COTS product..it's ridiculous, I know.

Comment: @Matti, my understanding is that it applies to any software that is free.  I sent an email to management about the Microsoft tool, and the response was "I would prefer (request) that we find a commercial equivalent.  At the end of the day, there is nothing free about FOSS on <program name>"

Comment: @alexD: If I ever got an e-mail like that from anybody, I wouldn't want to be associated with them in any way any longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Help & Manual](http://www.helpandmanual.com/) which is extremely capable. It provides multiple outputs - chm, pdf, hlp and others. It is easy to use; can take very large help sources; and supports multiple languages and external translators; and can be used to generate application help (tool tips, etc.) I have no connection with the product or company, except as a very satisfied user. I do believe that its capabilities far outstrip Microsoft's free tool, though it is some years since I used the MS tool.